# How can I route URLs with variable "depth" in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently learning the MEAN-Stack and writing a tool in my API which multiplies a series of numbers. I have two questions for which the Express Documentation did not provide answers.

1. How can I route for URLs of variable depth?
   Currently, I'm doing the following:

```js
router.route('/multiply/:a/:b')

    .get(function(req,res){

        /*multiply*/

        return res.send(respone);
    });
```

As you can see I can only multiply 2 numbers this way, not as many as I like, and this approach routes anything, not just numbers for a & b.
So my second question is how do I route only for numbers as a & b?

Regards,
Claas M.

Comment: Probably it's better to use only one parameter `a` for example and then put in a serialised string with what you need as values

Answer (score 3):

You can use a wildcard route to match all numbers and then just do an explosion of the request params yourself:

```
// matches /multiply/1/3/4/5/32/4 etc...
router.route('/multiply/:numbers([0-9]+)*')
  .get(function(req, res){

    // req.params.numbers will equal /1/3/4/5/32/4
    var numbers = req.params.numbers.split('/');
    // ..
    // multiply numbers
    // ..
    return res.send(answer);

  });
```

Express Route tester is a really useful tool: http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

Comment: When I route `multiply/1/2/3 ` numbers contains only the 1 because `req.params.numbers` is only 1. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: @ClaasM. I don't know... Have you tried using the tester to make sure it matches your input?

Comment: In the tester it works but in my project it doesn't ... weird

Answer (score 0):

After I put far too much effort into this I concluded that it is easier to just use POST instead of putting the data into the URL.
But if someone knows a solution I will still be grateful.

```js
router.route('/multiply/:a/:b')

    .post(function(req,res){

        var array = req.body.numbers;
        /*multiply*/

        return res.send(respone);
    });
```